# How do I set up the delphi development environment in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, delphi

I started developing Delphi, but I do not know how to use Delphi in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *use* Delphi itself in Linux directly, as the Delphi IDE and compilers are all Windows-only executables. So, to run Delphi on a Linux system, you would have to run it inside of a Windows-based virtual machine running on Linux.

However, Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and later include a compiler that can *create* executables that run natively on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Also maXbox runs on Linux with a lot of scripts and also python for delphi.
we need Wine to run the scripting engine on debian linux.
maXbox is a script tool engine, compiler and source lib all in one exe to design and code your scripts in a shellbook! Pure Code for Object Scripting. Principle is simplicity and reduce to the max.
The App is “out of the box” (self containment) and needs no installation nor registration.

---

Release Notes maXbox 4.7.5.90 October 2021 mX47

---

Add 14 Units + 2 Tutorials
https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxbox/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortantley you cannot run Delphi in Linux.  But there is an amazing alternative.  It is called Lazarus!  It will run on Linux, Mac or Windows.  Get it at https://www.lazarus-ide.org/

I am actually surprised Lazarus isn't one of the most popular desktop development tools.  If you find it useful and you are capable you should also contibute to the project.  It has come a long ways in the past 10 years and with it I don't think you will need to even consider running Delphi on Linux.  Lazarus with FreePascal is sufficient!

Comment: You should reduce the opinionated/praising advertising in the answer and you should increase the amount of details regarding how to set up Lazarus on Linux to answer OP's question.  Perhaps you should point out a list of differences/deficiencies between Lazarus and Delphi so that the OP can easily find the features needed or the deal-killer lack thereof.  I am a reviewer of your answer.  Review was requested by StackOverflow for new users.  Your answer is much appreciated & helpful.  This comment is to help you take a good answer & make it excellent.

Comment: If you think that Lazarus is on par with Delphi, you apparently don't know Delphi very well. In particular the debugging leaves a lot to desire even compared to 20 year old Delphi 6. But yes, it's an option to look into. And I agree with @AndreasZUERCHER : Your post is either too long (too much unconditional praise for Lazarus) or too short (not enough real information about it).