# Compiling Pascal code with Lazarus LCL in Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, freepascal, lazarus

I am trying to compile/port on Linux a project which was originally written in Delphi on Windows. I have zero experience with Delphi on Windows and I have only very limited experience with Pascal.

I am running in **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS** and I have installed system-provided *Freepascal* and *Lazarus* with `sudo apt install fp-units-* lcl-* lazarus lcl fpc-*` (I've reached this list by trials and errors which helped me making progress towards trivial errors).

When I try to compile the top level program file, it fails as follows:

> ```
> $ fpc myprogr.dpr
> Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2+dfsg-9ubuntu1 [2022/04/11] for x86_64
> Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
> Target OS: Linux for x86-64
> Compiling myprogr.dpr
> myprogr.dpr(4,3) Fatal: Can't find unit Forms used by myprogr
> Fatal: Compilation aborted
> Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
> ```

which is weird because the stuff is there:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/forms.pp
> lazarus-src-2.2: /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/forms.pp
> $ ls -l /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/forms.pp 
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 92597 Jan  2  2022 /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/forms.pp
> ```

And that leads me to believe that something is wrong with the packages I am utilizing, but anyway I manually add the path, and the failure becomes:

> ```
> $ fpc -Fu/usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/ myprogr.dpr
> Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2+dfsg-9ubuntu1 [2022/04/11] for x86_64
> Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
> Target OS: Linux for x86-64
> Compiling myprogr.dpr
> Compiling /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/forms.pp
> forms.pp(24,2) Fatal: Cannot open include file "lcl_defines.inc"
> Fatal: Compilation aborted
> Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
> ```

Weird again as before because:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S lcl_defines.inc
> lazarus-src-2.2: /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/include/lcl_defines.inc
> $ ls -l /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/include/lcl_defines.inc
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 325 Jul 11  2020 /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/include/lcl_defines.inc
> ```

which I can make again progress with:

> ```
> $ fpc -Fu/usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/ -I/usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/include/ myprogr.dpr
> Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2+dfsg-9ubuntu1 [2022/04/11] for x86_64
> Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
> Target OS: Linux for x86-64
> Compiling myprogr.dpr
> Compiling /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/forms.pp
> Compiling /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/lclstrconsts.pas
> Writing Resource String Table file: lclstrconsts.rsj
> lclstrconsts.pas(481) Error: Writing Resource String Table file: > /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/lclstrconsts.rsj
> lclstrconsts.pas(481) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
> Fatal: Compilation aborted
> Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
> ```

And that continues the weirdness because:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S lclstrconsts.rsj
> lcl-units-2.2: /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/units/x86_64-linux/lclstrconsts.rsj
> $ ls -l /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/units/x86_64-linux/lclstrconsts.rsj
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 77783 Apr 11  2022 /usr/lib/lazarus/2.2.0/lcl/units/x86_64-linux/lclstrconsts.rsj
> ```

on top of which why is the compiler trying to write in global location rather than locally, but I digress.

Of course I looked at the Freepascal, Lazarus and a bit at the Ubuntu/Debian documentation (as well as generic web search), and nothing seemed to indicate this sort of problems...

I can jump into the rabbit hole and continue to reverse engineer all of this which potentially might even succeed compiling the project as I need, but instead I'd rather ask: am I doing something obviously wrong? Is the Freepascal and Lazarus projects in my distro broken (which means, should I rather compile them from source)?

Comment: You say that you are trying to compile Delphi code with FPC/Lazarus. Which [compiler mode](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse33.html) are you using?

Comment: @SilverWarior I was using the default mode which in my understanding is the most broadly compatible mode. After your comment, I did try to restrict to DELPHI mode only, by adding `-MDELPHI` switch to all compiler commands, and there is absolutely no change to what I described in the question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that program doesn't rely on Windows API to run? There is a unit called "Forms", which - in Delphi for Windows - is the main part of the Graphical GUI system, ie. the base form for all the graphical Dialogs. Unless there is a Linux specific version of that UNIT for FPC/Lazarus (Disclaimer: I am not familiar with FPC/Lazarus, just noticed the "Forms" unit which - in Delphi - is very WIndows-centric)

Comment: @HeartWare I spent some more time with this and I think the showstopper is what you say. However, before reaching that showstopper I needed to develop the compile line as I will report in the next comment (it's absolutely too long), which was really shocking to me. With other compilers I'm used to them already "knowing" where the OS-provided libraries are, so that's really strange with _FreePascal_

Comment: You didn't tell us why you want to use Lazarus instead of Delphi. Maybe you don't know that Delphi now support Linux and minimal conditional compilation is required to make the same code compile for Delphi, Linux, Android, IOS, MacOS provided to code make use of FMX framework instead of VCL (VCL is only Windows and heavily rely on Windows API, FMX is cross platform). For Linux, you have to install FmxLinux. If your application is Delphi/VCL, maybe you should first convert it to Delphi/FMX and then compile for Linux. Probably an easier path.

Comment: @fpiette THANKS! Because I don't know about it? This might be outdated but not by many years and it drove my to Lazarus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096199/ -- Looking at https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions it's still not clear to me if Linux is fully supported today. Plus, the goal is to eventually make the project Open Source, so not sure if Delphi is appropriate for that.

Comment: @davide Delphi itself is a Windows application as runs on Windows, but it can generate and debug Linux application (Intel based). Delphi is OK for OpenSource.

Answer (score 0):

As @HeartWare as noticed in a comment, the root cause of the impossibility to move forward is that the code uses Windows, Forms and many other Microsoft-specific units which do not have a Linux equivalent. This is unfortunate, but the most unfortunate aspect is that it's not clear at all from reading the documentation as a newbie, where it sounds like they have ported all units for all OSes.

But the most time consuming issue is that to compile the code I need a whopping

```
fpc -Fu/usr/share/lazarus/2.2.2/lcl/                    \
    -Fu/usr/share/lazarus/2.2.2/components/lazutils/    \
    -Fu/usr/share/lazarus/2.2.2/lcl/widgetset/          \
    -Fu/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/linux                \
    -Fu/usr/share/lazarus/2.2.2/lcl/nonwin32/           \
    -Fu/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/packages/pasjpeg/src/    \
    -Fi/usr/share/lazarus/2.2.2/lcl/include/            \
    -Fi/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/inc/                 \
    -Fi/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/linux                \
    -Fi/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/x86_64/              \
    -Fi/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/unix/                \
    -Fi/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/win/                 \
    -Fi/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.2.2/rtl/linux/x86_64/        \
    -FU./lib                                            \
    -MDELPHI                                            \
     my.dpr
```

This is both with the OS-provided and with the freepascal.org-provided (binary) installation. Being familiar with several other programming languages, this sounds really counterintuitive, in that the stuff in `/usr` is always automatically included by the compilers/interpreters because so specified in some global configuration, e.g. `/usr/include/` in C.

I still don't understand if that's the way it is for *FreePascal* or if it's something wrong with the binary installs for my OS which lack a global configuration setting.

Comment: Never include source libraries of Free Pascal in the search path. The default fpc.cfg should point to the precompiled files.  Probably the lazarus are not tied in automatically.  Automatically including paths of mostly unix only compilers are configured during configure/build. FPC is portable however and abstains from such tricks. The most logical solution is to simply compile from within lazarus.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort that was indeed my expectation, however even within Lazarus itself those libraries are not found, and that was my bafflement and reason to ask the question in the first place. Probably the `fpc.cfg` file provided by Ubuntu is broken *and nobody noticed*

Comment: Within lazarus, the project must have a dependency on the "LCL" (project inspector->required packages), and then it adds the paths by parameters by itself. The project conversion wizard afaik should have added that package to the projec.t You can build lazarus projects afaik with "lazbuild"